# Display time a cron job pulled data from a remote server

Tags: php, mysql, time, cron

I request XML information from a remote server every few minutes or so with a cron job. I store that information in a database, and then a separate file queries the database to display the information on a website. How can I display the exact time of the most recent update (as in the last time the cron job successfully ran the script which pulls the data from the remote server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the date in some file by calling `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` in your cron script. Then read the file with your display script.